# Out Of Memory Error at BitmapFactory.decodeResource

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

There is a while loop and inside that loop there is a call to function getCharView()
which creates the chart. In this function, `BitmapFactory.decodeResource` is called.

Inserting few records is fine but if I attempt to insert 8th record on my real device,
Out Of Memory error comes and the application crashes.

I understand that its because `BitmapFactory.decodeResource` is getting called in a loop
each time and so the bitmap dimentions are increasing which is causing a crash at certain point.

If I put the code- `cv = new ChartView();linearLayoutMap.put(date, cv.getChartView());views.add(cv.getChartView());` outside of loop then application does not crashes but that scrolling of bitmap gets stopped.

What can be done to stop crashing and make scrolling work too without crash after multiple inserts of records?

**My relevant code:**

```
Calendar scal = Calendar.getInstance();
scal.setTime(stDate);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

while (scal.compareTo(cal) < 0) {

//some more lines of code.....

cv = new ChartView();
linearLayoutMap.put(date, cv.getChartView());
views.add(cv.getChartView());
}


public class ChartView {
private Paint cPaint;


public LinearLayout getChartView() {

    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

newBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
getResources(), R.drawable.chart_bg).copy(
Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444, true);

canvas = new Canvas(newBitmap);
img.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);
img.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
float wFactor = (15 * scale);
float hFactor = (float) ((19.35) * scale);
float x1 = startHours * wFactor;
float x2 = endHours * wFactor;
float y1 = (2 * startHeight - 1) * hFactor;
float y2 = (2 * endHeight - 1) * hFactor;

canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, cPaint);
canvas.save(Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
linearlayout.addView(img);
}
});
return linearlayout;
}
}
```

Comment: what is size of "chart_bg"?

Comment: The size is `2.72 KB` with dimensions as `537 * 233`.

Comment: Please note that few records insert just fine but after certain limit (8th insert), it is raising exception. Insertion of each record affects the chart layout so new bitmap is created. Hence its in a while loop. If I keep it outside while loop, then no error but scrolling stops.

Comment: Is image different every time in loop? if not then you should not create copy of bitmap every time and use old one. And if possible have a look at my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16183635/out-of-memory-error-on-setimageresource/16184893#16184893. This will help you to scale down/resize your bitmap before using it so size in heap can be reduced.

Answer (score 0):

Android devices may have severe memory limitations. To overcome this, you will need to limit your bitmap's size. What you need to do is keep the bitmap as large as the viewable display, and not larger. When your user scrolls, update the bitmap instead of creating a new - larger one.

Comment: I am using `decodeResource.copy` which creates new bitmap. How to update then? Please note that few records insert just fine but after certain limit (8th insert), it is raising exception. Insertion of each record affects the chart layout so new bitmap is created. Hence its in a while loop. If I keep it outside while loop, then no error but scrolling stops.