# android image view crashes when big image is chosen for display

Tags: android, image, bitmapfactory

Many have asked this question before and got the right way to resolve it. but somehow its not working out for me. My app crashes when I try to choose a large image for display. I have tried to reduce the size by scaling it as well using BitmapFactory. This is not working. Please help.

my code:

```
    public void browse(View v){
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            int id = v.getId();
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            InputStream stream = null;

            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                Uri imgUri = data.getData();
                logopath = getPath(imgUri);

                //This block is to show the view
                    try {
                        if(bitmap != null){
                            bitmap.recycle();
                        }
                            stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
                            iv.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 100, 100, true));
                            //bitmap = shrinkBitmap(logopath,100,100);
                            //iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        } 
                    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                finally{
                    if (stream != null) {
                        try {
                                stream.close();
                            } 
                        catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        private Bitmap shrinkBitmap(String file, int height, int width) {
            BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bmpFactoryOptions);

            int heightRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight/(float)height);
            int widthRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth/(float)width);

            if (heightRatio > 1 || widthRatio > 1)
            {
             if (heightRatio > widthRatio)
             {
              bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = heightRatio;
             } else {
              bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = widthRatio; 
             }
            }

            bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bmpFactoryOptions);
         return bitmap;
        }
```

LogCat details:

```
    06-25 07:16:26.056: E/dalvikvm-heap(1973): Out of memory on a 48000016-byte allocation.
    06-25 07:16:26.206: E/AndroidRuntime(1973): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    06-25 07:16:26.206: E/AndroidRuntime(1973): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    06-25 07:16:26.206: E/AndroidRuntime(1973):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
    06-25 07:16:26.206: E/AndroidRuntime(1973):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:529)
    06-25 07:16:26.206: E/AndroidRuntime(1973):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:601)
    06-25 07:16:26.206: E/AndroidRuntime(1973):     at com.example.tg_db1.edit_company.onActivityResult(edit_company.java:113)
    06-25 07:16:26.206: E/AndroidRuntime(1973):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5293)
    06-25 07:16:26.206: E/AndroidRuntime(1973):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3315)
    06-25 07:16:26.206: E/AndroidRuntime(1973):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3362)
    06-25 07:16:26.206: E/AndroidRuntime(1973):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:141)
    06-25 07:16:26.206: E/AndroidRuntime(1973):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282)
    06-25 07:16:26.206: E/AndroidRuntime(1973):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    06-25 07:16:26.206: E/AndroidRuntime(1973):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    06-25 07:16:26.206: E/AndroidRuntime(1973):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
    06-25 07:16:26.206: E/AndroidRuntime(1973):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    06-25 07:16:26.206: E/AndroidRuntime(1973):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    06-25 07:16:26.206: E/AndroidRuntime(1973):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    06-25 07:16:26.206: E/AndroidRuntime(1973):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    06-25 07:16:26.206: E/AndroidRuntime(1973):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what does LogCat say?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html. load bitmaps efficiently.

Comment: see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16183635/out-of-memory-error-on-setimageresource/16184893#16184893

Comment: @MocialovBoris - logcat details added

Comment: What is your bitmap size? There is a limit for bitmaps. It depends from device to device, it can be 2048x2048 or 4096x4096 for displaying in image view.

Comment: image size I have are of 3000x4000

Comment: @ChintanRathod- though the code you have mentioned is nice, somehow I'm not able to fit this in my code. Since I'm using an input stream, I don't know how to change it for resources and utilize this :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Bitmap ThumbImage = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath), THUMBSIZE, THUMBSIZE);
```

[Refer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html)

Comment: This works fine for small images, but for larger ones I get OutOfMemoryError

Answer (score 0):

Use the sampling technique. More the sampling value, less the image size.
Hope you will be able to handle the OutOfMemory error, which causes due to low heap size rendering large images sizes.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 15;



Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
```

if you are using android 3.0 onward use  android:largeHeap="true" tag within application tag in manifest file..

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:largeHeap="true">
```

Comment: This is the error I get - E/dalvikvm-heap(361): 6291456-byte external allocation too large for this process.
E/GraphicsJNI(361): VM won't let us allocate 6291456 bytes
E/AndroidRuntime(361): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(361): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget

Comment: To some extent this is solving the issue. But still there are some persistent issues.