# ImageView OOM Issue

Tags: android, imageview, out-of-memory

Yesterday i was working with Image View in my app. I put an image. It was about 2.95 MB. And when i executed my application. My application crashed.

Then my friend suggested me that i should reduce the size of image.
I reduced the size of image (I used [this website](http://compressimage.toolur.com/) to compress that image)
I changed the image. I executed my application. And i was surprised.

My application was running.The error in Log was t Out Of Memory Error.

Is there a limit on image size in image view?
What is maximum size of image in imageView?

[Before posting this question i visited these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291272/android-image-view-crashes-when-big-image-is-chosen-for-display)
[And this website too](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Comment: `maximum size of image` it is per device. Read https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap Quick heads up: Image size does not matter. Only image resolution does.

Comment: Down voter should put the reason for Down voting in comment.So i could improve the mistake.

Comment: How can I improve  this post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you use a library for displaying images since they make caching, displaying errors, resizing and much more super simple.
Try these:

- [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)
- [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

About your question, I think it depends on the device although I'm not sure.